# Unlocking all ports in a router when using Linux

Tags: firewall, router

I heard that Linux's open ports are not very vulnerable, so a normal desktop Linux installation doesn't need a firewall. Still, my router (Dlink) blocks some ports, even in LAN.

Would it be a bad idea to unblock all the ports in my router?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, is a very bad idea, its true that Linux is more secure than others OS but **nothing** is 100% secure.

For example many Linux distribution has running the sshd by default, if you allow connections from internet to this port (22 by default) a hacker or a worm can do a brute force attack and get access to your Linux.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be a bad idea to unblock all the ports in my router?

Yes.

### tl;dr

I would not think of opening ports on a router that did not serve a legitimate purpose in my network, and even then I will want to filter the traffic on those ports.

### Reasoning

For discussion purposes, 'ports' are not usually where a specific vulnerability lies, its rather what service or application is listening on such and such a port.

Connections to ports are stateful. They have a source and a destination address. When your firewall blocks a port, it doesn't just turn that port off, it either disallows 'outgoing' or 'incoming' connections and it takes the state of each connection into consideration as well.

Regarding the information you have heard about open ports in Linux, that 'open ports are not very vulnerable' consider the following:

### Scenario 1

**Deny All Inbound that Is not Established, Allow All Outbound**

We have a router that blocks all incoming connections to all ports that are not already established by an allowed outgoing connection. Unless you are initiating the connection from the inside and establish the connection, no one can connect from the outside. Also imagine that all outbound connections on all ports are open. Is this safe?

### Scenario 2

**Allow All Inbound, Allow All Outbound**

Same as above but the router also allows unestablished outbound connections on all ports, also known as 'wide ass open' configuration. Is this less safe?

### Scenario 3

**Deny All Inbound, Filter All Outbound**

Differs from Scenario 1 only in that the firewall also is configured to only allow certain outbound connections on specific whitelisted ports, (i.e. `443`, `80`, `22`). Is this more safe?

### Conclusion

Not taking any network address translation into account...

Unless you really don't care about security, I would say that Scenario 3 is the only scenario of the three overly simplistic scenarios above that is remotely secure. Explicit whitelisting of allowed outbound connections and explicit whitelisting (or complete disallowal) of inbound connections.

Scenario 2 is just waiting for someone to find a vulnerability to exploit in any service or program that is listening on a port. Granted `nat` configuration is beyond the scope of this answer, and most routers don't do a whole lot more listening if there is no `nat`ting going on.

Scenario 1 looks safer than the horrible scenario 2, but really if there are any malicious programs that are deployed from within your network they could conceivable reach through your firewall and wreak all manner of evil on your network with this configuration. Cryptolocker I'm looking at you. This type of router configuration is by far the most common, but it is only slightly more secure than Scenario 2 (read not that much).